# VB6 App using COM Interop works fine in IDE, but compiled EXE crashes

Tags: vb6, interop

I am currently working on an app in VB6 that uses COM Interop libraries written in C# using the .NET 2.0 framework.

I used regasm.exe to register the tlb files from the .NET dlls using the /codebase switch. I was then able to successfully build and run the application in the VB6 IDE with no issues. The .NET code uses a config file, so I added it to the VB6 directory and it read from the configurations fine.

However, I then compiled an EXE file from the project an ran it on the same machine as the IDE is running on. I coupled the EXE with the config file just as I had done in debugging with the VB6.EXE, but when the app executes the first call to a method in one of the .NET classes, it throws a run-time error indicating an "Automation Error".

In my Declarations, I instantiate the following objects from the .NET classes, which seems to work fine.

```
Private objSession As New Session
Private curFolder As Folder
Private colFolderTemplates As New FolderTemplateCollection
Private objLicense As New License
```

However, the Automation Error comes up at runtime when the first line is executed:

```
Call objSession.Configuration.Configure(connectionString)
```

I tried adding the .NET dlls to the same directory as the Release EXE and re-registering the tlb files, but it did not help. Any suggestions on what I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, shot in the dark.  Things to try:

Explicitly new up the Session object (as well as License and FolderTemplateCollection):

```
Private objSession as Session
Set objSession = new Session
```

Automation error indicates that the GUIDs from the .NET assembly are not persisting.  To do so, do this in your C# code - this then guarantees that all Interfaces/Classes/Virtual tables persist, no matter how many times you compile your c# code:

```
[Guid("9AC71CA7-6F82-44A3-9ABE-75354B514A46")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IManager
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Display(ADODB.Recordset recordSet);
    [DispId(2)]
    void Close();
    [DispId(3)]
    string UserName { get; set; }
    [DispId(4)]
    string Password { get; set; }
    [DispId(5)]
    string Database { get; set; }
    [DispId(6)]
    string Server { get; set; }
    [DispId(7)]
    ICriteria Criteria { get; set; }
}

[Guid("B9BB5B84-8FBD-4095-B846-EC072163ECD3")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]    
[ProgId("MyApp.Manager")]
public class Manager : IManager
{
    void Display(ADODB.Recordset recordSet) 
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that my public types are qualified as ComVisible, but my assemblies are not. If I mark the assemblies as ComVisible and assign them a GUID, would that help or hurt the situation?

Comment: Adding a GUID never hurts anything.

Comment: Seems that the issue was actually rooted in a config file used by the .NET code - still not sure why it runs in the IDE using the same config. But I have noted your points above for future changes. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the issue of the config file is tricky with interop and running things in the IDE, because when u kick off an app in the IDE, VB6.exe is the hosting app, thus the .config file must be in that folder.  I would lookup procmon or filemon to see what, in fact, is getting hit under various conditions.