# Use Type Library (.tlb) in a VB6 project, ActiveX create object fail

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vb6, regasm

I created a dll and tbl files from C# Visual Studio 2008.

I `Regasm AssemblyName.dll /tlb: FileName.tlb /codebase` to register it to my local server.

Use the tlb reference. Compile it, it runs fine in my development PC.

After I make an exe, run it on other PC, error message "ActiveX fail to create object" is prompted.

Do I need to Regasm for every machine I deploy to?

What if there is no Visual Studio in deployment PC? No Regasm can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do that as a part of the install.  But that's only part of it.  You also have to markup all the public methods with attributes to make sure that the recompile does not accidentally compile the methods in the wrong order.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627563/vb6-app-using-com-interop-works-fine-in-ide-but-compiled-exe-crashes/4631223#4631223)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you need to do this as part of your install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be required to run `RegAsm` on every single client machine. If your component changes you will need to run `RegAsm ... /unregister`, replace your component with the new one and run `RegAsm` again.

In order for your C# DLL to work you will need to relevant framework installed on the machine as well (in your case .NET Framework 3.5)

I would consider using an installer as this can do some of the heavy lifting work of registering / unregistering and automatically installing the framework if required.